# High performance 3 Way Quick Sort Implementation

Tags: c++, strings, sorting, c++17, quick-sort

My implementation of `3 way quick sort` for strings.

It supposed to sort very large set of 800,000,000 objects.

This is why I added `Lense` class.
Suppose you have object like this:

```
struct User{
   int id;
   std::string name;
};
```

Then `Lense` class should be something like this:

```
struct UserLense{
    auto const &operator()(User const &a) const{
        return a.name;
    }
};
```

I especially cared about NOT to overflow the stack.

I use `shell sort` if recursion get too deep. I choose this sort because it is not recursive and is relatively fast.

I also kept the `insertion sort` as well, only reason is - everyone doing it this way.
When I try with real data, I probably remove `insertion sort` and replace it with `shell sort`.

I tried to separate 3 way partitioning (Dutch National Flag) in separate function, but code become more unclear.

Do not like how tail recursion happen, but similar to 3 way partitioning, code become more unclear.

Thank you in advance!

Here is the code:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <cstdio>   // also provide size_t

namespace three_way_quicksort_implementation_{
    constexpr short CUTOFF_INS  = 8;
    constexpr short CUTOFF_DEEP = 32;

    namespace{

        template<typename It>
        void swapIt(It a, It b){
            using std::swap;
            swap(*a, *b);
        }



        enum class M3{
            a,
            b,
            c
        };

        template<typename T>
        constexpr static M3 max3(T const &a, T const &b, T const &c){
            if (a > b){
                if (a > c)
                    return M3::a;
                else
                    return M3::c;
            }else{
                if (b > c)
                    return M3::b;
                else
                    return M3::c;
            }
        }

    } // namespace


    template<typename Lense>
    struct Insertion_Sort{
        template<typename It>
        void operator()(It first, It last, size_t digit) const{
            for (It i = first; i < last; ++i)
                for (It j = i; j > first && compare(j, j - 1, digit); --j)
                    swapIt(j, j - 1);
        }

    private:
        constexpr static auto subAt(std::string_view s, size_t digit){
            return digit < s.size() ? s.substr(digit) : "";
        }

        template<typename It>
        constexpr static bool compare(It a, It b, size_t digit){
            Lense _;

            return subAt(_(*a), digit) < subAt(_(*b), digit);
        }
    };



    template<typename Lense>
    struct Shell_Sort{
        template<typename It>
        void operator()(It first, It last, size_t digit) const{
            size_t const size = std::distance(first, last);
            size_t step = size - 1;

            for(;;){
                bool sorted = false;

                while ( ! sorted ){
                    sorted = true;

                    for (size_t i = 0; i < size - step; ++i){
                        auto j = i + step;

                        if (compare(first + i, first + j, digit)){
                            swapIt(first + i, first + j);

                            sorted = false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (sorted && step == 1)
                    break;

                step = step / 2;

                if (step < 1)
                    step = 1;
            }
        }

    private:
        constexpr static auto subAt(std::string_view s, size_t digit){
            return digit < s.size() ? s.substr(digit) : "";
        }

        template<typename It>
        constexpr static bool compare(It a, It b, size_t digit){
            Lense _;

            return subAt(_(*a), digit) > subAt(_(*b), digit);
        }
    };



    // Based on:
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972635/efficient-string-sorting-algorithm
    // https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/3-way-radix-quicksort-in-java/

    template<typename Lense>
    struct Quick3Way_Sort{
        template<typename It>
        void operator()(It first, It last, size_t digit, size_t deep) const{
            return sort(first, last, digit, deep);
        }

    private:
        template<typename It>
        constexpr static void median(It first, It last, size_t digit){
            It mid = first + ((last - first) >> 1);

            if (charAt(mid, digit) < charAt(first, digit))
                swapIt(first, mid);

            if (charAt(mid, digit) < charAt(last, digit))
                swapIt(last, mid);

            if (charAt(first, digit) < charAt(last, digit))
                swapIt(first, last);
        }

        template<typename It>
        void sort(It first, It last, size_t digit, size_t deep) const{
            ++deep;

            // controls tail recursion.
            for(;;){
                auto const distance = std::distance(first, last);

                if (distance <= 1)
                    return;

                if (distance <= CUTOFF_INS){
                //  printf("Cut Off: distance %zu\n", std::distance(first, last) );

                    Insertion_Sort<Lense>{}(first, last, digit);
                }

                if (deep > CUTOFF_DEEP){
                //  printf("Cut Off: too deep recursion %zu\n", std::distance(first, last) );

                    Shell_Sort<Lense>{}(first, last, digit);
                }

                auto lt = first;
                auto gt = last - 1;
                auto it = first + 1;

                median(lt, gt, digit);

                // partition

                auto const pivot = charAt(lt, digit);

                while (it <= gt) {
                    auto const t = charAt(it, digit);

                    if (t < pivot)
                        swapIt(lt++, it++);
                    else if (t > pivot)
                        swapIt(it, gt--);
                    else
                        ++it;
                }

                // handle tail recursion

                auto const max = max3(
                            std::distance(first, lt),
                            std::distance(lt, gt + 1),
                            std::distance(gt + 1, last)
                );

                switch(max){
                case M3::a:
                    if (pivot >= 0)
                        sort(lt, gt + 1, digit + 1, deep);

                    sort(gt + 1, last, digit, deep);

                    // sort(first, lt, digit, deep);

                    // prepare tail recursion

                    last = lt;

                    break;

                case M3::b:
                    sort(first, lt, digit, deep);

                    sort(gt + 1, last, digit, deep);

                    if (pivot >= 0){
                        // sort(lt, gt + 1, digit + 1);

                        // prepare tail recursion

                        first = lt;
                        last  = gt + 1;
                        ++digit;

                        break;
                    }

                    return;

                case M3::c:
                    sort(first, lt, digit, deep);

                    if (pivot >= 0)
                        sort(lt, gt + 1, digit + 1, deep);

                    // sort(gt + 1, last, digit, deep);

                    // prepare tail recursion

                    first = gt + 1;

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    private:
        constexpr static int charAt(std::string_view s, size_t digit){
            return digit < s.size() ? s[digit] : -1;
        }

        template<typename It>
        constexpr static int charAt(It it, size_t digit){
            Lense _;

            return charAt(_(*it), digit);
        }
    };



    template<typename Lense, typename It>
    void doInsertionSort(It lo, It hi) {
        size_t const digit = 0;

        return Insertion_Sort<Lense>{}(lo, hi, digit);
    }

    template<typename Lense, typename It>
    void doShellSort(It lo, It hi) {
        size_t const digit = 0;

        Shell_Sort<Lense>{}(lo, hi, digit);
    }

    template<typename Lense, typename It>
    void doThreeWayQuickSort(It lo, It hi) {
        size_t const digit = 0;
        size_t const deep  = 0;

        Quick3Way_Sort<Lense>{}(lo, hi, digit, deep);
    }



    struct StandardLense{
        template<typename T>
        T const &operator()(T const &a) const{
            return a;
        }
    };
}

template<typename Lense = three_way_quicksort_implementation_::StandardLense, typename It>
void threeWayQuickSort(It first, It last){
    using namespace three_way_quicksort_implementation_;

//  return doInsertionSort<Lense>(first, last);
//  return doShellSort<Lense>(first, last);
    return doThreeWayQuickSort<Lense>(first, last);
}





#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void testPrint(T const &data){
    for(auto const &x : data)
        std::cout << "- " << x << '\n';

    std::cout << "--------------------------" << '\n';
}

// #include "sortdata.h"
// in real code I use array of 10,000 - 20,000 strings.
// you have to replace this part,
// else it will proceed with Insertion sort.
std::string_view data[] = {
    "aaaa",
    "zzzzzzzzzzz",
    "xxxx",
    "zzzzzzzzzzz123456789",
    "bbbb",
};

int main(){
    threeWayQuickSort(std::begin(data), std::end(data));
//  std::sort(std::begin(data), std::end(data));

    if constexpr(0)
        testPrint(data);

    bool const b = std::is_sorted(std::begin(data), std::end(data));

    std::cout << ( b ? "OK" : "Error" ) << '\n';

    if constexpr(0)
        testPrint(data);
}
```

---

**Update**

I did put the sort in real world use:

The speedup with real world data is 32%.

The speedup with made up data is 27%.

Recursion of 32th level never happened and `shell sort` never kick in. I guess I wont change it to `non-recursive heap sort`.

---

**Update**

Final code is here:
https://github.com/nmmmnu/HM4/blob/master/include/threewayquicksort.h

When I use with real live data, this configuration kick recursion more than 16 only two times and `shell sort` sort array of size 6-7 elements.

if `insertion sort` is removed, the result have similar performance speed.

Comment: Why shell sort when the recursion gets too deep, instead of the more usual heap sort? Was it faster in practice perhaps? They're both O(1) space, but shell sort has a less good worst-case time complexity

Comment: hmmm. may be you are right. I love shell sort and I had it already implemented.
however heapsort is even easier, since std::stable_sort is heap sort, also there is make_heap / sort_heap. also heapsort is guaranteed O n log n

Answer (score 5):

## Library headers

We include `<cstdio>` but never use it.

Conversely, we use `std::cout` but never include `<iostream>`.

`std::size_t` is misspelt throughout the code.

With those issues fixed, the code compiles without warnings.

## Terminology

The template type `Lense` is called a *projection* in the Standard Library algorithms, including `std::sort`.  I recommend using the standard terminology so that users know what to expect.

## Use the standard library

Instead of writing `swapIt()`, just use `std::iter_swap()`.

If we use `std::invoke()` instead of calling the projection directly, we'll be able to accept pointers to data or function members as well as free functions - that's much more flexible, and what the standard library sort functions do.

## Useless class

The three `*_Sort` classes have no state; they don't need to be classes at all.  Replacing with a template functions makes the code much simpler (and eliminates the need for the `do*Sort()` functions).

Comment: Thanks a lot. stdio imports size_t. I always use size_t and not std:size_t. Projection - I agree, will rename it, also will use invoke. The classes has state - it is the template parameter. Also I expect that probably will need to pass the projection as constructor parameter, that depends when I use it in real world app (will happen very soon)

Comment: How did you compile the code to see if library is never used? Any compiler flag I am not aware of?

Comment: Just inspection - I fixed that and the `std::size_t` before I even attempted to compile.

Comment: The template parameter is not state; it is a part of the type (just as it is part of a template function).  State is something that differs from instance to instance.  Try it: you'll see that there's no need for those classes.

Comment: `<cstdio>` declares `std::size_t`.  It's allowed to also define `size_t`, but that's not a requirement, so portable code cannot depend on that.